# Link libmpich to android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries, static-linking, undefined-reference

I have generated Uclib using buildroot and used it to compile mpich for ARM devices.Then I created Android project and copied libmpich.a and the  Include folder to the project here is the Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
# static library info

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libmpich
LOCAL_MODULE := libmpich
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuilt/libmpich.a 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuilt/include
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libmpich
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# wrapper info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../prebuilt/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libmpich
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

after ndk-build i got the following error

```
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(initthread.o):initthread.c:function PMPI_Init_thread: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2bool'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(msgprint.o):msgprint.c:function MPIU_Usage_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stdout'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(msgprint.o):msgprint.c:function MPIU_Error_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(msgprint.o):msgprint.c:function MPIU_Internal_error_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(msgprint.o):msgprint.c:function MPIU_Internal_sys_error_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(msgprint.o):msgprint.c:function MPIU_Msg_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stdout'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(dbg_printf.o):dbg_printf.c:function MPIU_dbg_printf: error: undefined reference to 'stdout'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(dbg_printf.o):dbg_printf.c:function MPIU_dump_dbg_memlog_to_stdout: error: undefined reference to 'stdout'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2int'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2int'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2int'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2int'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2bool'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2bool'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2bool'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2str'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(param_vals.o):param_vals.c:function MPIR_Param_init_params: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2str'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(mpid_abort.o):mpid_abort.c:function MPID_Abort: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(mpid_vc.o):mpid_vc.c:function MPIDI_Populate_vc_node_ids: error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(mpid_vc.o):mpid_vc.c:function MPIDI_Populate_vc_node_ids: error: undefined reference to '__ctype_b'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(init.o):init.c:function PMPI_Init: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2str'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(strerror.o):strerror.c:function MPIU_Strerror: error: undefined reference to '__xpg_strerror_r'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(simple_pmi.o):simple_pmi.c:function accept_one_connection: error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(simple_pmi.o):simple_pmi.c:function PMI_Init: error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(sock.o):sock.c:function MPIDU_Socki_event_enqueue.isra.1: error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'
jni/../prebuilt/libmpich.a(sock.o):sock.c:function MPIDU_Sock_listen: error: undefined reference to 'MPL_env2range'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libndk1.so] Error 1
```

I don't understand why it is not linking correctly and what is missing

Update :
when I add libmpl.a to the project all MPL errors disappeared

Comment: Did you build your `libmpich.a` with an android toolchain? To be on the safe side, use the same toolchain as the one you invoke with **ndk-build** for **libndk1.so**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem occured because your static lib `libmpich.a` has dependance on another lib.

You have two diffenrent way to solve this issue :

1. Import any library needed by your `libmpich.a` as static library in your `Android.mk` as static library. The problem of this approach is that can be very long and painful if you have a lot dependance.
2. Build `libmpich` as a dynamic library, as dynamic library are package with their dependance. I do know how you build you `libmpich` library so i don't know if this will be hard to achieve. Once you have `libmpich.so` import it in your `Android.mk` as a dynamic library instead of a static one.

Comment: when I added libc.a to the projet the errors disappeared , although  there is still run time errors